# Trouble with Displaying ViewPager in a Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Help me with this problem of mine, im quite confuse on how to display/call ViewPager inside my main_activity.xml

Im quite new to android and i was having a hard time displaying this viewpager..

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private SimpleSideDrawer mNav;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ed8699")));
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
    mNav = new SimpleSideDrawer(this);

    mNav.setLeftBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_behind_left_simple);


    ImageButton button= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mNav.closeLeftSide();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
  return true;
} 

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {

    int itemId = item.getItemId();
    switch (itemId) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        mNav.toggleLeftDrawer();

        break; }

    return true;
}
```

TabsPagerAdapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            // 新着情報  fragment activity
            return new FirstTab();
        case 1:
            // パーティ fragment activity
            return new SecondTab();
        case 2:
            // ビューティ fragment activity
            return new ThirdTab();
        case 3:
            // 海外レポ  fragment activity
            return new FourthTab();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 4;
    }

}
```

My ViewPagerMainActivity

```
    public class ViewPagerMainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies","Movies" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="379dp" >

      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height= "900dp"
          android:background="#f08ea0">

          <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="500dp"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

               <include layout="@layout/view_pager"/>

          </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

View_pager.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create layout with Sliding Drawer and View Pager in XML layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.androidviewpagerapp.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myviewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Replace your Main activity with following source code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ViewPager viewPager;
 MyPagerAdapter myPagerAdapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myviewpager);
  myPagerAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
  viewPager.setAdapter(myPagerAdapter);

 }

 private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

  int NumberOfPages = 5;

  int[] res = { 
   android.R.drawable.ic_alert,
   android.R.drawable.ic_camera,
   android.R.drawable.ic_compass,
   android.R.drawable.ic_directions,
   android.R.drawable.ic_gallery};
  int[] backgroundcolor = { 
   0xFF101010,
   0xFF202020,
   0xFF303030,
   0xFF404040,
   0xFF505050};

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return NumberOfPages;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
   return view == object;
  }

  @Override
  public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {


      TextView textView = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
      textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
      textView.setTextSize(30);
      textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
      textView.setText(String.valueOf(position));

      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
      imageView.setImageResource(res[position]);
      LayoutParams imageParams = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      imageView.setLayoutParams(imageParams);

      LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
      layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
      LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
      layout.setBackgroundColor(backgroundcolor[position]);
      layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
      layout.addView(textView);
      layout.addView(imageView);

      final int page = position;
      layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, 
      "Page " + page + " clicked", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }});

      container.addView(layout);
      return layout;
  }

  @Override
  public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
   container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
  }

 }

}
```

Use this code for your requirement. This is working for me. Hope this will help you. If you have any further query then post your comment.

Comment: I just want to call or display viewpager in the activity_main.xml and also how will you implement or call it on MainActivity...